# Should I have my own server for storing the photos users post via my app?

Tags: ios, photo, data-storage

I developed an app that posts photos to the user's photo album on Facebook.I thought to myself that when the app will be on the App Store, there is a slight chance that millions of people would publish photos (I wish).

In that case, what server will store all that photo data? Should I supply my own server?
In what cases do I need to supply my own back-end server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=76191543919

"Facebook generates and stores four images of different sizes, which translates to a total of 60 billion images and 1.5PB of storage."

This means that all of Facebook's photos (a massive amount of data) are stored on Facebook's servers. Your application will just move the pictures form the device to Facebook's servers. You will need no back-end server if all of the uploading is done on the device, because the pictures will go straight to Facebook's servers.